# Atualizar um h:outputText do banco de dados de um p:autoComplete

Tags: java, primefaces

Estou com uma aplicação de atendimento médico e tenho a seguinte dúvida: quando utilizar o componente `p:autoComplete` do PrimeFaces para pesquisar o nome do paciente que tem o atributo `dataNascimento`, quero que o `h:outputText` receba a idade vindo do banco de dados.

```
<p:autoComplete id="nome"
                value="#{cadastroPrimeiraConsultaBean.pessoa.nome}" 
                completeMethod="#{cadastroPrimeiraConsultaBean.porNome}"  
                var="pessoa" itemLabel="#{pessoa.nome}" itemValue="#{pessoa}"
                forceSelection="true" dropdown="true" />

<p:outputLabel value="Data de Nascimento:" for="dataNascimento" />
                <h:outputText  value="cadastroPrimeiraConsultaBean.pessoa.dataNascimento id="dataNascimento"/>
```

Poderiam me ajudar a como fazer resolver esse problema.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar no seu autoComplete:

```
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="IDdoOutPutText" process="@this"/>
```

Se não setar o paciente, adicione um listener pra setar o paciente no seu bean, nesse mesmo ajax.

Comment: Rafael, pra fazer esse listener, tenho que pegar pelo id?
Exemplo: 

public Pessoa porId(Long id) {
  return manager.find(Pessoa.class, id);
 }

Comment: Sim, eu recomendaria fazer pelo id.

Comment: <p:outputLabel value="Nome do Paciente:" for="paciente" />
<p:autoComplete placeholder="Digite o nome do paciente" id="paciente" value="#{cadastroPrimeiraConsultaBean.primeiraConsulta.pessoa}"
completeMethod="#{cadastroPrimeiraConsultaBean.completarNome}" var="paciente" itemLabel="#{paciente.nome}" itemValue="#{paciente}" forceSelection="true" dropdown="true" >
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="prontuario" process="@this" listener="#{cadastroPrimeiraConsultaBean.completarId}"/>
    </p:autoComplete>